# Django inlineformset_factory with queryset

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views, inline-formset

I need to filter foreignkey select options on a form based on an object id passed by a view. 
I have the following view:

```
@login_required()
def QAView(request, equipamento_id):
    form = ActividadeForm()
    equipamento = Equipamento.objects.get(id=equipamento_id)
    testes_list = Teste.objects.filter(equipamento=equipamento_id)  
    form1 = inlineformset_factory(
              Actividade, Resultado, form=ResultadoForm, 
              exclude=('actividade',), extra=len(testes_list))

    context = {'equipamento_id': equipamento_id, 
               'data':datetime.now(), 'equipamento': equipamento, 
               'form': form, 'testes_list': testes_list, 
               'form1': form1}
    template = 'SFM/Equipamento/QA.html'
    return render(request, template, context)
```

Here are my forms:

```
class ActividadeForm(forms.ModelForm):      
    class Meta:
        model = Actividade
        fields = ['tipo']
        exclude = ['conclusoes']


class ResultadoForm(forms.ModelForm):
    frequencia = forms.CharField(max_length=50)
    tolerancia = forms.CharField(max_length=255)
    #def __init__(self, equipamento_id, *args, **kwargs):
        #super (ResultadoForm,self ).__init__(*args,**kwargs)
        #self.fields['teste'].queryset = Teste.objects.filter(equipamento=equipamento_id)
    class Meta:
        model = Resultado
        exclude = ['actividade']
```

This passes all the testes (which is a foreignkey to Teste Model) to the form. What I need is to query this foreignkey to get only the testes related to equipamento_id given by the view. Teste has a manytomany relation to Equipamento. 
If I do:

```
form1 = inlineformset_factory(Actividade, Resultado, form=ResultadoForm(equipamento_id), exclude=('actividade',), extra=len(testes_list))
```

and define **init** method commented in ResultadoForm, I get the following error:

```
Traceback:

File "C:\Users\i11931\Programas\Python3.5.1\lib\site-packages\django-1.9-py3.5.egg\django\core\handlers\base.py" in get_response
  149.                     response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "C:\Users\i11931\Programas\Python3.5.1\lib\site-packages\django-1.9-py3.5.egg\django\core\handlers\base.py" in get_response
  147.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "C:\Users\i11931\Programas\Python3.5.1\lib\site-packages\django-1.9-py3.5.egg\django\contrib\auth\decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  23.                 return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\i11931\Documents\DjangoProjects\IPO\SFM\views.py" in QAView
  37.       exclude=('actividade',), extra=len(testes_list))

File "C:\Users\i11931\Programas\Python3.5.1\lib\site-packages\django-1.9-py3.5.egg\django\forms\models.py" in inlineformset_factory
  1049.     FormSet = modelformset_factory(model, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\i11931\Programas\Python3.5.1\lib\site-packages\django-1.9-py3.5.egg\django\forms\models.py" in modelformset_factory
  847.                              error_messages=error_messages, field_classes=field_classes)

File "C:\Users\i11931\Programas\Python3.5.1\lib\site-packages\django-1.9-py3.5.egg\django\forms\models.py" in modelform_factory
  545.     return type(form)(class_name, (form,), form_class_attrs)

File "C:\Users\i11931\Documents\DjangoProjects\IPO\SFM\forms.py" in __init__
  23.       self.fields['teste'].queryset = Teste.objects.filter(equipamento=equipamento_id)

File "C:\Users\i11931\Programas\Python3.5.1\lib\site-packages\django-1.9-py3.5.egg\django\db\models\manager.py" in manager_method
  122.                 return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\i11931\Programas\Python3.5.1\lib\site-packages\django-1.9-py3.5.egg\django\db\models\query.py" in filter
  790.         return self._filter_or_exclude(False, *args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\i11931\Programas\Python3.5.1\lib\site-packages\django-1.9-py3.5.egg\django\db\models\query.py" in _filter_or_exclude
  808.             clone.query.add_q(Q(*args, **kwargs))

File "C:\Users\i11931\Programas\Python3.5.1\lib\site-packages\django-1.9-py3.5.egg\django\db\models\sql\query.py" in add_q
  1243.         clause, _ = self._add_q(q_object, self.used_aliases)

File "C:\Users\i11931\Programas\Python3.5.1\lib\site-packages\django-1.9-py3.5.egg\django\db\models\sql\query.py" in _add_q
  1269.                     allow_joins=allow_joins, split_subq=split_subq,

File "C:\Users\i11931\Programas\Python3.5.1\lib\site-packages\django-1.9-py3.5.egg\django\db\models\sql\query.py" in build_filter
  1199.             condition = lookup_class(lhs, value)

File "C:\Users\i11931\Programas\Python3.5.1\lib\site-packages\django-1.9-py3.5.egg\django\db\models\lookups.py" in __init__
  19.         self.rhs = self.get_prep_lookup()

File "C:\Users\i11931\Programas\Python3.5.1\lib\site-packages\django-1.9-py3.5.egg\django\db\models\fields\related_lookups.py" in get_prep_lookup
  98.                     self.lookup_name, self.rhs)

File "C:\Users\i11931\Programas\Python3.5.1\lib\site-packages\django-1.9-py3.5.egg\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py" in get_prep_lookup
  744.             return self.get_prep_value(value)

File "C:\Users\i11931\Programas\Python3.5.1\lib\site-packages\django-1.9-py3.5.egg\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py" in get_prep_value
  976.         return int(value)

Exception Type: ValueError at /SFM/Equipamento/6/QA/
Exception Value: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'ResultadoForm'
```

But if I replace form1 by:

```
form1 = ResultadoForm(equipamento_id)
```

I am able to filter the testes related to that equipamento_id but I cannot create the inline relations. Why is this? How can I pass that equipamento_id to the inlineformset in order to make a queryset?? Please Help...

Comment: Update your question with the full stacktrce and the forms

Comment: Updated... @e4c5 , added the ValueError Traceback that I get

Comment: post  a few lines around line 37 in your views.py say from line 30 to 45

Comment: @e4c5 those are the lines corresponding to QAView posted above...

Comment: The error occurs when i pass form=ResultadoForm(equipamento_id) in the inlinefomset defining the __init__ method with a queryset filter.

Comment: I was thrown off by the fact that that method was commented out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the problem

```
 return type(form)(class_name, (form,), form_class_attrs)
```

This is where your form is initialized. The first parameter that is passed to the `__init__` method of your form is the class name of the form a String. However your `__init__` looks like this

```
def __init__(self, equipamento_id, *args, **kwargs):
    super (ResultadoForm,self ).__init__(*args,**kwargs)
    self.fields['teste'].queryset = Teste.objects.filter(equipamento=equipamento_id)
```

The first parameter here is `equipamento_id` and that's assigned 'ResultadoForm' but you are using it as an integer in the next line in the query filter. Hence the error. Looking at the source code for [modelform_factory](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/forms/models.py#L463) it isn't clear how you an actually pass   `equipamento_id` as a parameter via inlineformset_factory.

you will have to try something like

```
 equipamento_id = kwargs.pop('equipamento_id')
```

But I am unsure how this can be sent through inlineform_set.

Comment: Thank you very much for your explanation. It was very clear. I lack some of the basic knowledge and messed up with the parameter types. I tried the suggested change but still no luck. I am getting a different error so you were wright. I won't mark as an answer hoping that someone can still give me a solution to this specific problem but your answer has definitely solved that error.

Comment: Yes, you are right to keep it open. But an upvote wil be gratefully appreciated :). May I also suggest that you post a new question too. in that new question you can say "I need to filter foreignkey select options on a form based on an object id passed by a view." and then that you tried inline_formset but ran into the difficulty of passing parameters to the form.

Comment: I will mark your answer. I was able to solved it because i posted another question as you suggested. Your tips allowed to me solve this problem so thank you very much. The trick was to do formset = ArticleFormSet(form_kwargs={'user': request.user}) following @Shang Wang answer.

Comment: great to know that it got sorted out.